# Which Rails' documentation is most up to date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

And which one is most noob friendly?

Comment: You want an API doc or an introduction?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your definition of "documentation".

Most up to date: http://api.rubyonrails.org/
Most user friendly (and also up to date): http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 0):

There is also http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/ and http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org